# Join tables and Union All/ Pivot/ Unpivot?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, join

I have four tables in a database as:

Table 1: **Employee_Details**

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
| Employee ID | Name  | Department |DateofJoining |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|             |       |            |              |
| e1          | name1 | d1         | date1        |
| e2          | name2 | d2         | date2        |
| e3          | name3 | d3         | date3        |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Table 2: **Employee_SkillSet**

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| EmployeeID | SkillId | SkillName | SkillExperience | SkillRating |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|            |         |           |                 |             |
| e1         | s1      | skill1    |               11|           11|
| e1         | s2      | skill2    |               12|           12|
| e1         | s3      | skill3    |               13|           13|
| e2         | s1      | skill1    |               21|           21|
| e2         | s2      | skill2    |               22|           22|
| e2         | s3      | skill3    |               23|           23|
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Table 3: **Employee_Certifications**

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
| EmployeeID | CertificationID |  Name  |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|            |                 |        |
| e1         | c1              | cname1 |
| e1         | c2              | cname2 |
| e2         | c3              | cname3 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Table 4: **Other_Details**

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| EmployeeId | TotalExp | Qualification | Specialization |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|            |          |               |                |
| e1         | 1        | q1            | abc            |
| e2         | 2        | q2            | xyz            |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Now, the above four tables have to be queried to get an output like:

```
+------------+-------+-------------+---------------+---------+----------------+----------------+------------+----------------+--------+--------------+------------------+
| EmployeeID | Name  | Department  | Qualification | Tot_Exp | Specialization | Certifications | Skill1_Exp | Skill1_Rating  | ……………… | Skill100_Exp | Skill100_Rating  |
+------------+-------+-------------+---------------+---------+----------------+----------------+------------+----------------+--------+--------------+------------------+
|            |       |             |               |         |                |                |            |                |        |              |                  |
| e1         | name1 | d1          | q1            | 1       | spec1          | c1,c2          | 11         | 11             | ……………. | …………………      | ………………………        |
| e2         | name2 | d2          | q2            | 2       | spec2          | c3             | 21         | 21             | ……………. | …………………      | ………………………        |
+------------+-------+-------------+---------------+---------+----------------+----------------+------------+----------------+--------+--------------+------------------+
```

So far, I have been able to perform a query (using dynamic SQL) on Table 2-Employee_SkillSet to resemble something like below:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| EmpId | S1_Exp | S1_Rating | S2_Exp | S2_Rating | S3_Exp | S3_Rating |....
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|       |        |           |        |            |       |           |
| e1    | 11     | 11        | 12     | 12         | 13    | 13        |....    
| e2    | 21     | 21        | 22     | 22         | 23    | 23        |....
| e3    | 31     | 31        | 32     | 32         | 33    | 33        |....
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
P.S. S is for Skill which I abbreviated over here  to conserve space
```

My question is, how do I join the other three tables row-wise to this to get the desired output?

I should probably point out that I am pretty new to joins,pivot/unpivot, cross-apply and everything in-between, so even if the answer is pretty straightforward I cant seem to figure it out.

**EDIT**

Creation script:

```
CREATE TABLE Employee_Details ( 
    [Employee ID] nvarchar(2),
    [Name] nvarchar(10),
    Department nvarchar(2),
    DateofJoining nvarchar(5)
)

INSERT INTO Employee_Details VALUES
('e1', 'name1', 'd1', 'date1'),
('e2', 'name2', 'd2', 'date2'),
('e3', 'name3', 'd3', 'date3')

CREATE TABLE Employee_SkillSet (
    EmployeeID nvarchar(2),
    SkillId nvarchar(2),
    SkillName nvarchar(10),
    SkillExperience int,
    SkillRating int
)

INSERT INTO Employee_SkillSet VALUES
('e1', 's1', 'skill1', 11, 11),
('e1', 's2', 'skill2', 12, 12),
('e1', 's3', 'skill3', 13, 13),
('e2', 's1', 'skill1', 21, 21),
('e2', 's2', 'skill2', 22, 22),
('e2', 's3', 'skill3', 23, 23)

CREATE TABLE Employee_Certifications (
    EmployeeID nvarchar(2),
    CertificationID nvarchar(2),
    [Name] nvarchar(10)
)

INSERT INTO Employee_Certifications VALUES
('e1', 'c1', 'cname1'),
('e1', 'c2', 'cname2'),
('e2', 'c3', 'cname3')

CREATE TABLE Other_Details (
    EmployeeId nvarchar(2),
    TotalExp int,
    Qualification nvarchar(2),
    Specialization nvarchar(100)
)

INSERT INTO Other_Details VALUES
('e1', 1, 'q1', 'abc'),
('e2', 2, 'q2', 'xyz')
```

Creation scripts:

Comment: Isn't it just a join on empID? The only thing you might need is something like a STUFF FOR XML PATH('') statement for concatenating columns (e.g. certifications).

Comment: Yes, it is a join on EmpId. The thing I cant figure out is how to pivot the resulting table so that all data corresponding to one EmpID is in a single row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

- FOR XML PATH('') to get comma separated values
- Dynamic SQL so you don't need to change query if new skills arrives
- Pivoting to make rows to columns

My solution is below:

```
DECLARE @col nvarchar(max),
        @sql nvarchar(max)

SELECT @col = (
    SELECT DISTINCT ','+QUOTENAME(SkillName + STUFF([name],1,5,'_'))
    FROM Employee_SkillSet es
    CROSS JOIN sys.columns sc
    WHERE sc.[object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'Employee_SkillSet')
            AND sc.column_id > 3
    FOR XML PATH('')
)
--That will generate the string:
--,[skill1_Experience],[skill1_Rating],[skill2_Experience],[skill2_Rating]...[skillN_Experience],[skillN_Rating]

SELECT @sql= N'
SELECT  ed.EmployeeID,
        ed.[Name],
        ed.Department,
        STUFF((
        SELECT '',''+Qualification
        FROM Other_Details
        WHERE ed.EmployeeID = EmployeeID
        FOR XML PATH('''')
        ),1,1,'''') as Qualification,
        STUFF((
        SELECT '',''+CAST(TotalExp as nvarchar(10))
        FROM Other_Details
        WHERE ed.EmployeeID = EmployeeID
        FOR XML PATH('''')
        ),1,1,'''') as TotalExp,
        STUFF((
        SELECT '',''+Specialization
        FROM Other_Details
        WHERE ed.EmployeeID = EmployeeID
        FOR XML PATH('''')
        ),1,1,'''') as Specialization,
        STUFF((
        SELECT '',''+CertificationID
        FROM Employee_Certifications
        WHERE ed.EmployeeID = EmployeeID
        FOR XML PATH('''')
        ),1,1,'''') as Certification'+@col+'
FROM Employee_Details ed 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT  EmployeeID,
                SkillName + STUFF(Skills,1,5,''_'') as [Columns],
                [Values]
        FROM (
            SELECT *
            FROM Employee_SkillSet
        ) as es
        UNPIVOT (
            [Values] FOR Skills IN (SkillExperience,SkillRating)
        ) unp
    ) as s
    PIVOT (
        MAX([Values]) FOR [Columns] IN ('+STUFF(@col,1,1,'')+')
    ) pvt
) as f
    ON f.EmployeeID = ed.EmployeeID'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Output:

```
EmployeeID  Name    Department  Qualification   TotalExp    Specialization  Certification   skill1_Experience   skill1_Rating   skill2_Experience   skill2_Rating   skill3_Experience   skill3_Rating
e1          name1   d1          q1              1           abc             c1,c2           11                  11              12                  12              13                  13
e2          name2   d2          q2              2           xyz             c3              21                  21              22                  22              23                  23
e3          name3   d3          NULL            NULL        NULL            NULL            NULL                NULL            NULL                NULL            NULL                NULL
```

NOTE: I use `SkillExperience,SkillRating` in UNPIVOT part, if there are more skill *properties* - then you can use one more variable like `@col` to pass comma separated values.

Comment: Thanks...this looks promising and the query is similar to what I was trying to achieve. I'll run the query for actual tables now and see what I get.

Comment: I am getting an error : Invalid column name 'EmployeeID'.

Comment: I thought it was a typo in your table description. Change `ed.EmployeeId` to `ed.[Employee ID]` in the query.

Comment: Did that. Worked like a charm. You are a lifesaver.Thank you

Comment: My pleasure! :)

Comment: Out of curiosity ... what exactly is happening in @col?

Comment: It takes all skill names (`skill1, skill2 ... skillN`) and takes names of columns from system table `columns` (`SkillExperience, SkillRating`) and do Cartesian join to get all possible combinations of skills and there properties. Than it lists them in one string, so you can pass it to dynamic query.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using dynamic SQL for skills, you could use this:

```
SELECT      ed.EmployeeID AS EmpID,
            ss1.SkillExperience AS S1_Exp,
            ss1.SkillRating AS S1_Rating,
            ss2.SkillExperience AS S2_Exp,
            ss2.SkillRating AS S2_Rating,
            ss3.SkillExperience AS S3_Exp,
            ss3.SkillRating AS S3_Rating
FROM        Employee_Details ed
INNER JOIN  Employee_SkillSet ss1 ON ed.EmployeeID = ss1.EmployeeID AND ss1.SkillName = 'skill1'
INNER JOIN  Employee_SkillSet ss2 ON ed.EmployeeID = ss2.EmployeeID AND ss2.SkillName = 'skill2'
INNER JOIN  Employee_SkillSet ss3 ON ed.EmployeeID = ss3.EmployeeID AND ss3.SkillName = 'skill2'
```

Now to complete it

```
WITH Certifications AS
(
SELECT  EmployeeId
       ,STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CAST(Name AS VARCHAR(10)) [text()]
         FROM Employee_Certifications 
         WHERE EmployeeId = c.EmployeeId
         FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,' ') Certifications
FROM Employee_Certifications c
GROUP BY EmployeeId
)

,Skills AS
(
SELECT      ed.EmployeeID AS EmpID,
            ss1.SkillExperience AS S1_Exp,
            ss1.SkillRating AS S1_Rating,
            ss2.SkillExperience AS S2_Exp,
            ss2.SkillRating AS S2_Rating,
            ss3.SkillExperience AS S3_Exp,
            ss3.SkillRating AS S3_Rating
FROM        Employee_Details ed
INNER JOIN  Employee_SkillSet ss1 ON ed.EmployeeID = ss1.EmployeeID AND ss1.SkillName = 'skill1'
INNER JOIN  Employee_SkillSet ss2 ON ed.EmployeeID = ss2.EmployeeID AND ss2.SkillName = 'skill2'
INNER JOIN  Employee_SkillSet ss3 ON ed.EmployeeID = ss3.EmployeeID AND ss3.SkillName = 'skill2'
)

SELECT      ed.EmployeeID,
            ed.Name,
            ed.Department,
            od.Qualification,
            od.TotalExp,
            od.Specialization,
            c.Certifications,
            s.S1_Exp,
            s.S1_Rating,
            s.S2_Exp,
            s.S2_Rating,
            s.S3_Exp,
            s.S3_Rating         
FROM        Employee_Details ed
LEFT JOIN   Other_Details od ON od.EmployeeId = ed.EmployeeId
LEFT JOIN   Certifications c ON c.EmployeeID = ed.EmployeeID
LEFT JOIN   Skills s ON s.EmpID = ed.EmployeeID
```

Comment: The reason I am using dynamic sql is because the skills are more than 100. It wont do to add data for all 100 skill ids explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select TBl1.[EmployeeID],Tbl1.Name,Tbl1.Department,TBl1.Qualification, TBl1.TotalExp ,TBl1.Specialization,TBl1.[Certifications]
,Skill1_Exp,Skill1_Rating
,Skill2_Exp,Skill2_Rating
,Skill3_Exp,Skill3_Rating
From
(
    Select TBl1.[EmployeeID],Tbl1.Name,Tbl1.Department,Tbl4.Qualification, Tbl4.TotalExp ,Tbl4.Specialization,Tbl3.[Certifications]
    From Employee_Details Tbl1 Inner Join Employee_SkillSet Tbl2
    On TBl1.[EmployeeID]=TBl2.[EmployeeID]
    Inner Join 
    (
        SELECT Dtl.[EmployeeID],
                    STUFF((    SELECT ',' + Cer.CertificationID AS [text()]
                                FROM Employee_Certifications Cer
                                WHERE
                                Cer.[EmployeeID] = Dtl.[EmployeeID]
                                FOR XML PATH('')
                                ), 1, 1, '' )
                    AS [Certifications]
        FROM  Employee_Details Dtl
    ) as Tbl3
    On Tbl1.[EmployeeID]=Tbl3.[EmployeeID]
    Inner Join Other_Details as Tbl4
    On Tbl1.[EmployeeID]=Tbl4.[EmployeeID] 
    Group by TBl1.[EmployeeID],Tbl1.Name,Tbl1.Department,Tbl4.Qualification, Tbl4.TotalExp ,Tbl4.Specialization,Tbl3.[Certifications]
)as Tbl1
Inner Join
(
    Select Tbl1.[EmployeeID],Tbl1.skill1 as Skill1_Exp,Tbl2.skill1 as Skill1_Rating
    ,Tbl1.skill2 as Skill2_Exp,Tbl2.skill2 as Skill2_Rating
    ,Tbl1.skill3 as Skill3_Exp,Tbl2.skill3 as Skill3_Rating
    From
    (
        Select *
        from (seLECT [employeeID],SKILLNAME,SkillExperience FROM Employee_SkillSet )P
        PIVOT
        (max(SkillExperience )
            FOR SkillName IN([skill1], [skill2],[skill3])
        ) AS PivotSales 
    )as Tbl1
    Inner Join
    (
        Select *
        from (seLECT [employeeID],SKILLNAME,SKILLRATING FROM Employee_SkillSet )P
        PIVOT
        (
            max(SkillRating) 
            FOR SkillName IN([skill1], [skill2],[skill3])
        ) AS PivotSales
    )as Tbl2
    On Tbl1.[EmployeeID]=Tbl2.[EmployeeID]
) as Tbl2
On Tbl1.[EmployeeID]=Tbl2.[EmployeeID]
```